# Finish ActivityGroup which making combine of both Top and Bottom Tab

Tags: android, android-activity

I made ActivityGroup which combined two activities one activity for TOP tab and second one for
**BOTTOM** tab and it works fine BUT
when I click in any activity on tab both tabs (top and bottom) still there however this activity don't have them.

My question now how I finish this ActivityGroup how I get rid of it when I click on any activity in this tabs. plz I need help

Here is my code :

```
 public class Multi extends ActivityGroup{
LinearLayout layout;
LinearLayout layout_s1;
LinearLayout layout_s2;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.multiview);

    layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.multiview_layout);
    layout_s1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_view_1);
    layout_s2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_view_2);

    LocalActivityManager mgr = getLocalActivityManager();

    layout_s1.addView((mgr.startActivity("MyOtherActivityInstance1", new Intent(this, Tab1.class))).getDecorView());
    layout_s2.addView((mgr.startActivity("MyOtherActivityInstance2", new Intent(this, Tab2.class))).getDecorView());


    }
   }
```

Comment: You have 7 questions so far, and zero accepted answers. Think bout it for a second please...

Comment: @MarekSebera ok i googled it before asking but no result now what shall i do ??